# Unknown character in Oracle data while loading into flat file

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to load Oracle data into a flat file using python 3 and getting following error. How to fix this? Python is not able to write these characters in text file. (OS : Windows 7)

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

It is caused by following data - 
BELLÃPIERRE

[http://unicodelookup.com/#BELLÃ](http://unicodelookup.com/#BELL%C3%83)PIERRE/1

[image]

Comment: This exact question has been asked many hundreds of times. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+%22charmap+codec+can%27t%22

Comment: According to the error message, the problem is related to *reading* the data, not *writing*. It looks like you should try UTF-8 for decoding the text instead of whatever 8-bit encoding is used by default.